# Event listner and Toggle click conflict

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling

I have a menu & sub-menu that needs to obey the following behaviour:

1. Open/Close with an toggle icon press for menu, and down icon row press for sub menu.
2. Close both when there is a click outside it's boundaries.

Both onclick openings are working fine. Close outside boundary is also working fine.
But when I click on icons to close they are not closing.

I tried

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

But it didn't work.

Below is the full code

```
const Menubar = () => {
  const [menuOpenState, setMenuOpenState] = useState(false);
  const handleMenuClick = (event) => {
    console.log("new menuOpenState " + !menuOpenState + event.target)
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    setMenuOpenState(!menuOpenState);
  };

  const [subMenuOpenState, subMenuMenuOpenState] = useState(false);
  const handleSubMenuClick = (event) => {
    console.log("new subMenuOpenState " + !subMenuOpenState + event.target)
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    subMenuMenuOpenState(!subMenuOpenState);
  };

  const menuRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null!)
  const subMenuRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null!)
  useOnClickOutside(menuRef, () => {
    console.log("menu handler")
    setMenuOpenState(false)
  });
  useOnClickOutside(subMenuRef, () => {
    console.log("submenu handler")
    subMenuMenuOpenState(false)
  });

  return (
    <div css={menubar}>
      <div css={logoHeader}>
        <a css={logoTitle} href="#">Title</a>
      </div>
      <nav ref={menuRef} css={navHeader} className={menuOpenState ? 'menuOpen' : 'menuClosed'}>
        <ul css={menuNav}>
          <li>
            <div onClick={handleSubMenuClick} css={subMenuItem}>
              <a>Services</a>
              {subMenuOpenState ?
                  <IoChevronUp css={subMenuToggle}></IoChevronUp> :
                  <IoChevronDown css={subMenuToggle}></IoChevronDown>
              }
            </div>
            {/*<ul css={subMenuNav} className={(subMenuOpenState) ? 'subMenuOpen' : 'subMenuClosed'}>*/}
            <ul ref={subMenuRef} css={subMenuNav} className={(subMenuOpenState) ? 'subMenuOpen' : 'subMenuClosed'}>
              <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Copywriting</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div css={menuToggle}>
        <a href="#" onClick={handleMenuClick}><FaBars css={hamburgerToggle} size={20}></FaBars></a>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

On Click outside handling.

```
const useOnClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const listener = (event) => {
        // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
        if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
          console.log("if condition called")
          return;
        }
        console.log("out of if 1"+ event.target)
        console.log("out of if 2"+ ref.current )

        handler(event);
      };
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
        document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
      };
    },
    [ref, handler]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the solution.

The issue in the code was related to event propagation and handling nested event listeners. Specifically, when clicking on the toggle icons to close the menu or sub-menu, the click event was propagating to the parent elements, causing them to reopen immediately.

I was using event.stopPropagation() and event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation() to prevent event propagation. However, due to the nested event listeners and the way the event propagation was handled, the propagation could not be stopped effectively.

Updated code solves this problem.

```
const Menubar = () => {
  const [menuOpenState, setMenuOpenState] = useState(false);
  const handleMenuClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setMenuOpenState(!menuOpenState);
  };

  const [subMenuOpenState, setSubMenuOpenState] = useState(false);
  const handleSubMenuClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setSubMenuOpenState(!subMenuOpenState);
  };

  const menuRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null!)
  const subMenuRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null!)
  useOnClickOutside([menuRef, subMenuRef], () => {
    setMenuOpenState(false);
    setSubMenuOpenState(false);
  })

  return (
    <div css={menubar}>
      <div css={logoHeader}>
        <a css={logoTitle} href="#">Title</a>
      </div>
      <nav ref={menuRef} css={navHeader} className={menuOpenState ? 'menuOpen' : 'menuClosed'}>
        <ul css={menuNav}>
          <li>
            <div onClick={handleSubMenuClick} css={subMenuItem}>
              <a>Services</a>
              {subMenuOpenState ?
                  <IoChevronUp css={subMenuToggle}></IoChevronUp> :
                  <IoChevronDown css={subMenuToggle}></IoChevronDown>
              }
            </div>
            {/*<ul css={subMenuNav} className={(subMenuOpenState) ? 'subMenuOpen' : 'subMenuClosed'}>*/}
            <ul ref={subMenuRef} css={subMenuNav} className={(subMenuOpenState) ? 'subMenuOpen' : 'subMenuClosed'}>
              <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Copywriting</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div css={menuToggle}>
        <a href="#" onClick={handleMenuClick}><FaBars css={hamburgerToggle} size={20}></FaBars></a>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const useOnClickOutside = (refs, handler) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < refs.length; i++) {
        if (refs[i].current && refs[i].current.contains(event.target)) {
          return;
        }
      }
      handler(event);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
    };
  }, [refs, handler]);
}
```

In this modified code, the useOnClickOutside hook accepts an array of refs instead of a single ref. This allows us to pass both menuRef and subMenuRef to the hook. The listener function checks each ref in the array to determine if the clicked element is inside any of the ref's elements or their descendants. If so, it returns early without executing the handler. This ensures that clicking on the menu or sub-menu elements will not trigger the outside click event.